# Redirecting to MFA of another account while connecting to Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I have two Office365 accounts belonging to the same organization. I can connect with account 1 and MFA pops up correctly for account1, but when I want to connect with account 2, MFA pops up for account1 (not account 2).

I tried to delete cookies and all temporary files, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What type MFA are you using and where are you trying to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are logging in and which MFA method you are using, you may  need to [manually remove the saved credentials](https://blog.headforcloud.com/2019/07/31/mis-behaving-office-365-mfa-and-app-passwords/).

If you go to aka.ms/mfasetup you can also verify the MFA info for each account and make sure that the prompts go to the right spot.